# How Can I get floor with sqrt in type Integral

Tags: haskell

I wrote simple function in Haskell, I would like check if number is prime with small optimazation. I don't have any idea how to write correct roundSqrt

```
roundSqrt :: Integral -> Integral
roundSqrt x = floor (sqrt (fromIntegral x))  


isPrime :: Integral t => t -> Bool
isPrime n = [i | i <- [2..k], n `mod` i == 0] == []
           where k =  roundSqrt(n)
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with that code? It works for me.

Comment: I get error:   `Expecting one more argument to ‘Integral’
    Expected a type, but ‘Integral’ has kind ‘* -> GHC.Prim.Constraint’
    In the type signature for ‘roundSqrt’:
      roundSqrt :: Integral -> Integral`

Comment: Ah, it should be `Integral t => t -> t`. Or even remove all type annotations.

Comment: Thanks, I already know why it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integral` is a typeclass, so it shouldn't be used as a type. You even used it correctly in `isPrime` type annotation. So, to make it work, you should write

```
roundSqrt :: Integral t => t -> t
```